# How to run tests in parallel by classes with TestNG and Selenium with POM Pattern

Tags: selenium, testng

I am using webdrivermanager with driver call.
But it retains the pom pattern and is difficult to construct in parallel using the threadlocal class.

My module is structured as below.

Some of my code.

Driver class

```
public class Driver {

public WebDriver setDriver(WebDriver driver, String browser, String lang) throws Exception {
    if (browser.contains("Chrome")) {
        
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().clearResolutionCache().clearDriverCache().setup();
            
        }
        options.addArguments(lang);

        driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        
        Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
        
    } else {
        WebDriverManager.iedriver().clearResolutionCache().clearDriverCache().setup();
        
    }
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    return driver;
   }
}
```

Next Pageclass

```
public class LoginPage{

private WebDriver driver; 

@CacheLookup
@FindBy(id = "j_domain")
public static WebElement domainField;

@CacheLookup
@FindBy(id = "j_username")
public static WebElement usernameField;

@CacheLookup
@FindBy(id = "j_password")
public static WebElement passwordField;

public LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
    
  }
}
```

Next Base testclass :

```
public class BaseTest {
  public WebDriver driver;

  public LoginPage loginPage;

  @Parameters({"browser"})
  @BeforeClass
  public void Setup(ITestContext context, String browsertype) throws Exception {
    
    pageFactory.driver.Driver driversetting = new pageFactory.driver.Driver();
    driver = driversetting.setDriver(driver, browsertype, "lang=ko_KR");
    
    context.setAttribute("webDriver", driver);
    
    loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
  
  }
}
```

Next testclass

```
public class Remotepc_Center extends BaseTest {

  @Test(priority = 1, enabled = true)
  public void a1(Method method) throws Exception {
   }
}
```

Using threadlocal I want sessions to be configured independently and tests running in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to follow the below sugggestions/recommendations in order for you to be able to work with Page Object Model and thread local variables, please do the following:

1. Make use of a library such as [autospawn](https://github.com/RationaleEmotions/autospawn) to handle the webdriver instances backed by thread local variables.
2. Make sure that you create Page Objects only within your test methods because that's the only place wherein your thread local variables would have a webdriver that can be accessed by the test method as well. Querying the thread local variable for retrieving the webdriver instance from within a configuration method such as `@BeforeClass` (in the testng world) is going to give you a different thread.

In TestNG context, only a `@BeforeMethod`, `@Test` and a `@AfterMethod` are guaranteed to run in the same thread.

For additional details on how to work with a thread local variable, you can perhaps refer to [my blog](https://rationaleemotions.com/parallel_webdriver_executions_using_testng/)

For the sake of completeness, including relevant code snippets for the thread local creation.

1. Define a factory that can create webdriver instances as below

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
 
class LocalDriverFactory {
    static WebDriver createInstance(String browserName) {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("firefox")) {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("internet")) {
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        if (browserName.toLowerCase().contains("chrome")) {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            return driver;
        }
        return driver;
    }
}
```

2. Define a driver manager class that looks like below:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
 
public class LocalDriverManager {
    private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> webDriver = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>();
 
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return webDriver.get();
    }
 
    static void setWebDriver(WebDriver driver) {
        webDriver.set(driver);
    }
}
```

3. Define a TestNG listener that looks like below

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethod;
import org.testng.IInvokedMethodListener;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
 
public class WebDriverListener implements IInvokedMethodListener {
 
    @Override
    public void beforeInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            String browserName = method.getTestMethod().getXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browserName");
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverFactory.createInstance(browserName);
            LocalDriverManager.setWebDriver(driver);
        }
    }
 
    @Override
    public void afterInvocation(IInvokedMethod method, ITestResult testResult) {
        if (method.isTestMethod()) {
            WebDriver driver = LocalDriverManager.getDriver();
            if (driver != null) {
                driver.quit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4. A typical test case would now look like below:

```java
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 
public class ThreadLocalDemo {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {
        invokeBrowser("http://www.ndtv.com");
    }
 
    @Test
    public void testMethod2() {
        invokeBrowser("http://www.facebook.com");
 
    }
 
    private void invokeBrowser(String url) {
        System.out.println("Thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        System.out.println("HashcodeebDriver instance = " + 
        LocalDriverManager.getDriver().hashCode());
        LocalDriverManager.getDriver().get(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is parallel execution per class possible instead of per-method parallel execution?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You would need to hoist your `@Test` annotation to the class level and then have the `singleThreaded` attribute set to true. In that case, you can't use a `ThreadLocal` variable, but you would need to perhaps employ a map driven approach to get/set the webdriver instance for a particular test method depending on which class it belongs to.